# graphiQL-query in Axios

Tags: javascript, graphql, axios

this query in GraphiQL works perfect:

```
{
  getSubContentListing(filter: "{\"contentSection\": \"home\"}") {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        contentSection
        contentTitle
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But if I include it in my Axios-query:

```
  let query = {
    query: `query {
      getSubContentListing(
        filter: "{\"contentSection\": \"home\"}") {
        edges {
          node {
            contentSection
            contentTitle
          }
        },
      }
    }`
  }
  axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: '/subcontent?apikey=abcdef',
    data: {
      query: query
    }
  })
```

ESLint give an Error "error: Unnecessary escape character: \" (no-useless-escape) "

If I build it as a variable like this:

```
  let query = {
    query: `query($filterSearch: String) {
      getSubContentListing(
        filter: $filterSearch) {
        edges {
          node {
            contentSection
            contentTitle
          }
        },
      }
    }`
  }
  axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: '/subcontent?apikey=abcdef',
    data: {
      query: query,
      variables: {
        filterSearch: JSON.stringify("{'contentSection': 'home'}")
      }
    }
  })
```

for ESLint it is OK, but the query didn't work.
Where is my mistake?

awant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash characters in the template string literal:

```
const queryString = `query {
  getSubContentListing(
    filter: "{\\"contentSection\\": \\"home\\"}") {
#             ^                ^    ^      ^
    edges {
      node {
        contentSection
        contentTitle
      }
    },
  }
}`;
```

Alternatively, you can create that string using `JSON.stringify`:

```
const filterSearch = "{\"contentSection\": \"home\"}";
const queryString = `query {
  getSubContentListing(
    filter: ${ JSON.stringify(filterSearch) }) {
    edges {
      node {
        contentSection
        contentTitle
      }
    },
  }
}`;
```

This can be written in different ways:

```
const filterSearch = "{\"contentSection\": \"home\"}";
const filterSearch = '{"contentSection": "home"}';
const filterSearch = JSON.stringify({contentSection: "home"});
```

The approach with the variable is a more comfortable way of doing this, not having to inline the `JSON.stringify` in the query, but your

```
const filterSearch = JSON.stringify("{'contentSection': 'home'}")
```

does not pass in the correct string value.

Comment: Tested both, but also there is the Error-Message:

{"errors":[{"message":"GraphQL query body is expected to be string, but got array"}]}

Comment: An array? That doesn't make sense. However, notice that in your code you have nested two objects with a `query` property in each other, there should probably be only one.

Comment: testet all variants, but ESLint give me this error: "Strings must use singlequote.(quotes)".

Comment: @awant Not with the `filterSearch = '{"contentSection": "home"}';` variant I hope

Comment: Yes Linter take this Line, but didn't work, now with Error: "Syntax Error: Expected Name, found String "contentSection"".

Comment: Now it works with this line: let filterSearch = JSON.stringify('{"contentSection": "home"}') - Thanks !